# Recursive list of files with names that don't contain a certain string

Tags: search, find

I have: a directory with many nested subdirectories and files.

I would like: a list of all files whose name doesn't contain a certain string.

Example file structure:

```
foo/
foo/bar/foobar.txt
foo/foo/foobartest.txt
foo/foobartest.txt
```

If I enter my query with the string "test" it should return only `/foo/bar/foobar.txt`

I suppose one would use `find` with some regex?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you want in the output.

```
ls -R | grep -v test
```

Or

```
find foo -type f | grep -v test
```

You can format the output with tools such as perl or awk

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get

> a list of all files **whose name** doesn't contain a certain string

you have to go with something like this:

`find foo/ -type f -exec bash -c "basename {} | grep -v 'test' > /dev/null && echo {}" \;`
This will match only by filename, but output a relative path as find would normally do.
May be someone can propose a more elegant solution?

If matching against relative path is okay you can go with the answer, provided by **@bodhi.zazen**:

`find foo -type f | grep -v test`

Comment: Thanks for this option, too, but for my purposes @bodhi.zazen has provided a sufficient solution.